# INSERT from JOIN inserts null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The need to insert values from 3 tables into another table called `myTable`. The required fields in myTable are:

```
[Id_student] int,
[id_subjects] int
[degrees] float
[st_Name] nvarchar(30) 
[Id_Class] int
[Id_Group] int 
[Class] nvarchar(15)
[group] nvarchar(15))` ..
```

I created the stored procedure below. But after viewing the table I found that only the passed parameters were saved! ie `@Id_student ,  @id_subjects , @degrees`. Can anyone explain what is wrong with this code?

```
CREATE storedprocedure mySp_myTable_insert
        @Id_student  int,
        @id_subjects int,
        @degrees     int
as

DECLARE @st_Name nvarchar(30) 
SELECT @st_Name  = pst.st_Name  FROM dbo.sudents  AS pst where pst.id_student=@id_student ;

INSERT [myTable]
    (
        [Id_student],
        [id_subjects],
        [degrees],
        [st_Name],
        [Id_Class],
        [Id_Group],
        [Class],
        [group]
    )

    (select
        @Id_student,
        @id_subjects,
        @degrees,
        @st_Name
        ,tc.Id_Class
        ,tg.Id_Group
        ,tc.Class
        ,tg.group
    from dbo.subjects sbj 
    inner join tGroup tg 
    inner join tClass tc
        on tc.Id_Class=tg.Id_Class 
        on sbj.Id_Group =tg.Id_Group 
    where sbj.id_subjects=@id_subjects)
```

Comment: @Siva, you should post this as an answer,

Comment: @Siva `INTO` is optional according to the T-SQL specs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: @Siva , thanks, but [Into] Is an optional keyword that can be used between INSERT and the target table.See[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: your SQL appears to be correct. Try running the `select` only to see what results you get (perhaps the data you're inserting is `NULL`)

Comment: @Siva I also wasn't aware of this until a few weeks ago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should drop the parentheses around the `SELECT` statement and fix the order of the `join`-`on` keywords/clauses.

Try this version:

```
CREATE storedprocedure mySp_myTable_insert
        @Id_student  int,
        @id_subjects int,
        @degrees     int
as

DECLARE @st_Name nvarchar(30) 
SELECT @st_Name  = pst.st_Name  FROM dbo.sudents  AS pst where pst.id_student=@id_student ;

INSERT [myTable]
    (
        [Id_student],
        [id_subjects],
        [degrees],
        [st_Name],
        [Id_Class],
        [Id_Group],
        [Class],
        [group]
    )
select
    @Id_student,
    @id_subjects,
    @degrees,
    @st_Name
    ,tc.Id_Class
    ,tg.Id_Group
    ,tc.Class
    ,tg.group
from dbo.subjects sbj 
inner join tGroup tg on sbj.Id_Group =tg.Id_Group
inner join tClass tc on tc.Id_Class=tg.Id_Class 
where sbj.id_subjects=@id_subjects

GO
```

Comment: can you try running the `select` only? does it return valid data?

Comment: yes It does.. but the fields( [st_Name],[Id_Class],[Id_Group],Class,       [group]) are null.

Comment: well then, the problem must be with the data which is null.

Comment: I'm sure that my data is OK, any way Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can show us some sample data. This way we'd be able to diagnose why there are `null`s in the results.